# gvim tab key doesn't work

Tags: vim

I have just started using vim and am using an existing .vimrc and .gvimrc. It works great, except the Tab key doesn't tab...it brings up a code completion plug-in. I don't know where to start as I am brand new to vim. How can I make the Tab key generate a tab???

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First, find out which script or plugin changed the meaning of your  key:

```
:verbose imap <Tab>
```

Then disable the offending plugin by removing it from your ~/.vim/plugins.

Comment: @CocoB: if that fixed it for you, consider accepting the answer.

Comment: If `:verbose imap <tab>` returns "No mapping found" but `:iunmap <tab>` makes the tab key work again, it is most likely that ctrl-i is mapped. Try `:verbose imap <C-i>`, you'll see that the tab key will execute what <C-i> is mapped to. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14642074/9157799

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is disable the tab mapping just do:

```
:iunmap <Tab>
```