# How to unmap TAB and do not make Ctrl-I invalid in VIM

Tags: vim

When I use vim in normal mode, I often press the TAB key accidentally, the key TAB do the same thing as Ctrl-I in default. I want to make the key TAB do nothing, so I put this line in the vimrc file:

```
nmap <TAB> :echo<CR>
```

Thus, the key TAB will do nothing, but this made the key Ctrl-I do nothing too.
So, how to make the TAB do nothing and the Ctrl-I work well as before in vim (in normal mode) ?

Comment: [It is possible in Xterm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/631241).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today, even in GVIM. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>non-alphabetic</kbd> cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>letter</kbd> vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>letter</kbd> cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` etc. This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated [various proposals](http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8).

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim 8 major release.

Comment: Thank you so much. I also found this impossible in this page [how to map <tab> and <c-i> independently](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/how-to-map-lt-tab-gt-and-lt-c-i-gt-independently-td1185417.html). Thus I should make myself not to press the TAB key accidentally.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really hope this gets sorted out soon - all the discussions seem to peter out eventually, which implies it requires a major code rethink. Here's a current(ish) thread: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/vim_dev/2bp9UdfZ63M/discussion

Comment: The current patchlevel of Vim 7.3 suggest that there'll be a new release (7.4?) soon. I hope this problem is tackled for a future Vim 8.0 then.

Comment: I've been assuming 7.4 was around the corner since patch ~400!

Answer (score 11):

I would advice to having `<TAB>` do something useful:

```
nmap <TAB> <C-W>
nmap <TAB><TAB> <C-W><C-W>
```

this way you can use `tab` for the window operations. Of course with this you cannot have the `ctrl-i` behavior. I map `,i` for this:

```
nnoremap ,i <C-I>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that `ctrl-tab` work as default `ctrl-i` when `tab` is remaped.

Works in macvim. I did not check in others vims.