# What is the reason that Ctrl+I and Tab keys send same codes?

Tags: vim, terminal, keyboard

Does anybody can to explain what is the reason that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd> keys send same code?
I could only figure out it's because of "historical reasons".

For example, this fact can affect on behavior of vim with some bindings like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14641942/how-to-unmap-tab-and-do-not-make-ctrl-i-invalid-in-vim/).

Comment: You can also use `Ctrl`+`[` to get an `Esc` character.

Answer (score 7):

I think this has to do with how Tab is encoded in ascii.

If we look at this [ascii table](http://www.unix-manuals.com/refs/misc/ascii-table.html) and at the man page for ascii (copied below)

```
Oct   Dec   Hex   Char                        Oct   Dec   Hex   Char
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
000   0     00    NUL '\0'                    100   64    40    @   
001   1     01    SOH (start of heading)      101   65    41    A   
002   2     02    STX (start of text)         102   66    42    B   
003   3     03    ETX (end of text)           103   67    43    C   
004   4     04    EOT (end of transmission)   104   68    44    D   
005   5     05    ENQ (enquiry)               105   69    45    E   
006   6     06    ACK (acknowledge)           106   70    46    F   
007   7     07    BEL '\a' (bell)             107   71    47    G   
010   8     08    BS  '\b' (backspace)        110   72    48    H   
011   9     09    HT  '\t' (horizontal tab)   111   73    49    I   
012   10    0A    LF  '\n' (new line)         112   74    4A    J   
013   11    0B    VT  '\v' (vertical tab)     113   75    4B    K   
014   12    0C    FF  '\f' (form feed)        114   76    4C    L   
015   13    0D    CR  '\r' (carriage ret)     115   77    4D    M
```

we can see that tab is the 9th character (in decimal) in the ascii character set. Each one of the non printing characters can be typed by using control and ith letter in the alphabet. Since I is the 9th letter in the alphabet `<C-I>` is Tab. This is also why carriage returns show up as `^M`.

As for why vim treats them the same. It is probably a hold over from a very long time ago when using control keys for this purpose was important.

Comment: This is off the top of my head so I don't actually know how accurate this is.