# <C-PageUp> in vim via putty

Tags: vim, tabs, putty

My .vimrc contains

```
nnoremap <C-PageUp>   :tabprevious<CR>
nnoremap <C-PageDown> :tabnext<CR>
nnoremap <C-t>        :tabnew<CR>
inoremap <C-PageUp>   <Esc>:tabprevious<CR>i
inoremap <C-PageDown> <Esc>:tabnext<CR>i
inoremap <C-t>        <Esc>:tabnew<CR>
```

and it works in Ubuntu.

But in Windows PuTTY it's useless. Ctrl+PageUp scrolls terminal 1 line up. Ctrl+PageDown do nothing.

Is it possible to switch tabs in vim with combination Ctrl+PageUp from PuTTY and if there is no way to do it, is there any terminal emulator for windows which support this action?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14641942/how-to-unmap-tab-and-do-not-make-ctrl-i-invalid-in-vim This may help.

Answer (score 2):

I understand you wish to use **C-PageUp** but I recommend using the default as follows for switching tabs.

To move to the next tab use

```
gt
```

To move to the previous tab use

```
gT
```

I use the following mappings for other tab related shortcuts

```
map <leader>tn :tabnew<cr>
map <leader>to :tabonly<cr>
map <leader>tc :tabclose<cr>
map <leader>tm :tabmove<cr>
map <leader>te :tabedit <c-r>=expand("%:p:h")<cr>/
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, finally I added new maps, `<c-h>` and `<c-l>`, they work nicely over putty and keep your hands on the home row.

Comment: It's ok, but in this case it's not possible to switch tabs from insert mode.

Comment: Besides, <C-Page[Up|Down]> is a default hotkey for mostly all applications with tabs such as sublime, notepad++ and all browsers.
I'm trying to push it reflexively.
But I think I have to give up for now.

Comment: Insert mode is for inserting :) Alternatively, you can do <c-o><c-h>/<c-o><c-l> from insert mode.

Comment: PS: alternative: check my [`vimrc`](https://github.com/juanjux/My-Vim-dir/blob/master/.vimrc) to see how to add a number to every tag in text and GUI modes:  (lines 69 and 138-179), then you can easily do Ngt (or <c-o>Ngt in insert mode) to change to the tab N.