# Tab is doing weird things when I edit html

Tags: vim

Here is the relevant piece of vimscript:

```
inoremap <c-i> <i></i><esc>F<i
```

I added this to ~/.vim/ftplugin/html.vim to make writing in italics easier. For some reason, whenever I'm in insert mode (even in a non-html file), and I press the tab key, I get `<i></i>` in my text. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: `CTRL-I` is equivalent to `TAB`. See [this](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/3570/6698) answer to know why.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should be using `inoremap <buffer> <c-i>...` if you don't intend to infect non-HTML files.

Secondly, Ctrl-I and Tab are equivalent. AFAIK you can't map one without affecting the other. You might want to select a different mapping. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14641942/how-to-unmap-tab-and-do-not-make-ctrl-i-invalid-in-vim) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, you cannot map `<Tab>` / `<C-I>` separately, even in GVIM. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This also applies to `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim release.